# Angular 6 library with forRoot and AOT - Function calls are not supported in decorators

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

I am trying to include a custom library into my Angular application, but I am having a problem with the `forRoot` function of the library.

I have rolled out my application as a cause, since I've created a starter angular-cli project and can confirm the same error happening there with `ng build --prod`:

> ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule' Function calls
>   are not supported in decorators but 'CustomLibModule' was called.

**Lib versions**

Angular `6.1.10`,

Angular-cli `6.2.1`,

@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr `0.8.5`,

---

**Library module**

The `forRoot` method of the library:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
})
export class CustomLibModule {

  public static forRoot(key: string, options?: ConfigOptions, version = SupportedVersions.V3): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CustomLibModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: PUBLIC_KEY, useValue: key},
        {provide: OPTIONS, useValue: options},
        {provide: VERSION, useValue: version},
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

The provider options are Angular `InjectionToken`'s that are used in the lib.

---

**Application code**

The application is calling the library in the following way:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CustomLibModule.forRoot(env.KEY), <-- This causes the error, where `CustomLibModule`, without forRoot, is valid.
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The `env.KEY` is nothing more then a string. Replacing it with `''` doesn't work either.

---

The library was created with the following tutorial, [how to build Angular 6 library](https://medium.com/@suwigyarathore/write-your-own-library-in-angular-6-741d44d4a356), and is in the Angular 6 template. I have not modified the ts-config.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "core": [
        "dist/custom-lib"
      ],
      "core/*": [
        "dist/custom-lib/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, I fixed doing this: try NOT to use barrels in your module(import {xxx} from './xxx/xxx.component.ts' and not './xxx/' and check if your public_api using 'xxx/index' instead of 'xxx/', because my metada.json was so incomplete.